# How do i create my own binary serializer using BinaryReader and BinaryWriter?

Tags: c#, .net

I basically want to create my own binary serialization class, kinda what `BinaryFormatter` class is doing. How can i use `BinaryReader` and `BinaryWriter` classes to accomplish this.
I don't want any code but an idea.
Thanks.
PS: Please don't tell me to use `BinaryFormatter`.

Comment: This is impossible to answer accurately if you don't say what's wrong with BinaryFormatter.  How *exactly* does your version need to work better?

Comment: I am doing this as a learning exercise. No problem with BinaryFormatter at all + BinaryFormatter is not supported on CF and i would like some lightweight formatter for both ways.

Comment: @Hans oh don't get me started :) I could talk about ***that*** all afternoon...

Comment: you might also want to look at existing public binary serialization formats; there are a good few to choose from

Comment: I've created my own "better" binary serializer before, to intercept simple cases (boolean, int, e.g.) and store the data using a simple scheme or unencoded. It's better because it uses much less space than the encoded binary data, and in this situation the simple cases represent the vast majority of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see how serialisation could be implemented you can look at the c# sourcecode of  [sharpserializer](http://www.sharpserializer.com/en/index.html). The sourcecode can be found [here](http://sharpserializer.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets). The code also works under windowsmobile, silverlight.

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately, you need to choose a strategy per type, and then just switch to each; BinaryWriter has methods to write Int32, String, etc - so a basic approach is to use lots of reflection and a switch on GetTypeCode of te FieldInfo/PropertyInfo's effective type.

Personally, having done this, I would actually *avoid* BinaryReader / Writer, though - and go straight for the Stream (with a floating byte[] buffer for working in).

Getting advanced, you might reduce the amount of reflection by using meta-programming to pre-compile something per member or per-type.

Other things to consider:

- What header data do you need (if any) to mark each data field
- How are you going to pack sub-objects/inheritance/lists

Both are fairly easy to solve, of course

Comment: Why would you avoid `BinaryReader` and `BinaryWriter`?  I've used them to (mostly) good effect. I'll admit to some annoyance now and then, but in general I prefer them. What do you see as the advantages to using a `byte[]` buffer?

Comment: @Jim - in my case, the data formats aren't an exact match to what BinaryReader/Writer would choose (protobuf uses varint variable length encoding), and there is a fair amount of binary juggling involved; may as well wrote it directly to a scratch buffer and minimise the number of Read/Write calls. Note the buffer is flushed when full - I don't assemble the entire thing in memory (that would have large memory overheads). But mainly the first reason : it just wouldnt offer me anythig much

Comment: Yeah, variable length encodings are kind of a pain with those. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using something like [ProtoBuf .Net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/), which you can setup using attributes on your class and it will handle all the binary serializing/deserializing.

I recently had to augment that to provide customer serialization support inside a generic class with a more compact format. Like Marc mentioned, just have code that handles serializing/deserializing a specific type and then switch to run the code for the type of the specific object you want to write.

Here is a basic outline of an approach I took in order to allow serialization of data inside a generic class:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);

writer.Write(_size);
for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++)
    _indices[i].AddToStream(writer);

if (_serializeDataToStream == null)
    _serializeDataToStream = (Action<BinaryWriter, int, T[]>)GetTypeSpecificSerializationMethod();

_serializeDataToStream(writer, _size, _data);

return stream.ToArray();
```

This is inside generic class, _serializeDataToStream is static so it only has to be looked up once per generic type

```
private Delegate GetTypeSpecificSerializationMethod()
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(double))
    {
        MethodInfo method = this.GetType().GetMethod("SerializeDouble", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        return Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<BinaryWriter, int, T[]>), method);
    }
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(ushort))
    {
    ...


private static void SerializeDouble(BinaryWriter writer, int size, double[] data)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        writer.Write(data[i]);
    }
}
```